# Update SSO using MetadataService class

Tags: metadata-api, single-sign-on

I am using below code for updating SAML Identity Type in one of the SSO settings from **UserId** to **FederationId** : -

```java
 MetadataService.MetadataPort service = new MetadataService.MetadataPort();
 service.SessionHeader = new MetadataService.SessionHeader_element();
 service.SessionHeader.sessionId = UserInfo.getSessionId();
 service.timeout_x = 40000;  
 List<MetadataService.Metadata> lst_AllMetaData = new List<MetadataService.Metadata>();
 List<String> ssos =  new List<String>();
     ssos.add('Test_SSO');       
 List<MetadataService.SamlSsoConfig> SSO =
                 (List<MetadataService.SamlSsoConfig>) service.readMetadata('SamlSsoConfig',ssos).getRecords();
                 
 for(MetadataService.SamlSsoConfig singlesso : SSO){
     System.debug('------------'+singlesso.samlEntityId);
     System.debug('------------'+singlesso.loginUrl);
     System.debug('------------'+singlesso.identityMapping);
     singlesso.identityMapping = 'FederationId';
     lst_AllMetaData.add(singlesso);
 }           
 List<MetadataService.SaveResult> results = service.updateMetadata(lst_AllMetaData);
 System.debug(results[0]);
```

But i am getting an error :

> SaveResult:[apex_schema_type_info=(http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata,
> true, false),
> errors=(Error:[apex_schema_type_info=(http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata,
> true, false), extendedErrorDetails=null,
> extendedErrorDetails_type_info=(extendedErrorDetails,
> http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata, null, 0, -1, false),
> field_order_type_info=(extendedErrorDetails, fields, message,
> statusCode), fields=null, fields_type_info=(fields,
> http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata, null, 0, -1, false),

Does anyone have any idea on this ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there additional error details? there is no message in the error details you posted. Without knowing exact error, it is hard to guess the reason.

Comment: That is the only error I was getting.. did you see any fundamental mistake ?

Comment: getting the below error:  "Property 'useConfigRequestMethod' not valid in version 42.0----FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION"